# A new list data structure optimized for insertions at any place?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I was looking for a list data structure optimized for **arbitrary insertions**, at any index, but I didn't found a lot of information about this problem, except maybe some interesting Binary Trees and a lot of painful array manipulations.

Binary Trees are useful, but I think that Generalized Lists are better for this purpose. I don't know why they are not as widely used as trees, anyway.

However, Generalized Lists are not enough by themselves for implementing lists: they must have a property that may keep them clear, not degenerated in a lot of sublists after random insertions.

> **I propose this propery**: *A Generalized list cannot have sublist with equal or more items than its containing list. If this property is
>   violated, it can be restored if we spill the elements of the sublist
>   in the parent list.*

For example **(1 2 3 (4 5 7 (9 1) 0))** is "unstable", because it has a sublist that has more "slots" than its parent list (not counting elements recursively). It can be rewritten to **(1 2 3 4 5 7 (9 1) 0)** using the previous proposed property.

Also, new  elements would create new sublists, instead of just being added directly into the parent list. For example:

If a new element "x" is added to index 1 of

```
(1 2 3 5)
```

it would then be

```
(1 ("x" 2) 3 4)
```

If "y" is added to index 1, then it would be

```
(1 (("y" "x") 2) 3 4)
```

which is "unstable", so it would be transformed to

```
(1 ("y" "x" 2) 3 4)
```

which is also unstable, so it would be transformed to

```
(1 "y" "x" 2 3 4)
```

My questions are these: **Does this data structures had been described before?** I mean, I think it can be really useful, and it's almost **trivial**. If it existed before, why is not so known?  **Is it really useful?** Does it has a name? I do think it's useful, but I may be wrong.

I [implemented it in a persistent fashion](https://github.com/fluorine/SpongeList), but my code (Java) is a little messy and ugly, although it seems to work and it's also documented. What do you think?

Comment: It's an interesting idea to amortize the cost of insertions into an array, but it looks to me like accessing an item requires a sequential search. Potentially skipping over sub-lists, of course, but your array of int, for example, becomes essentially an array of sublists (which are themselves arrays of sublists, etc.) So it's really a tree. An indexed skip list (see the answer below) will likely give better performance and a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks for that information! I hope it would be useful someday.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to skip lists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: I don't think this is at all similar to a skip list. A skip list is best used as a ordered data structure. The OP is talking about an indexed data structure. Skip list doesn't do that well.

Comment: @JimMischel Adding indexing capability to a skip list is a technical detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist But I don't insist that OP's lists are *very* similar to skip lists, because frankly I don't fully understand OP's idea.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to read the linked PDF to see how insertion is handled. Assuming it's reasonable, then it's definitely analogous to the OP's idea. The OP's idea is essentially a way to amortize the cost of insertions in a sequential list by maintaining sublists, but I don't see how it can handle indexing efficiently.

Comment: Well, Skip lists are not deterministic. This data structure is.

Comment: @Josell There are deterministic skip lists, see references in the Wikipedia article.